# U-boot tool error: Binman: cannot import name QUIET_NOTFOUND

Tags: python, u-boot, imx6

I am attempting to create an image with a 0x0 padded header of 0xFFF bytes before an imx6 .imx image for use with a tool that will burn this image to the base of NOR flash with meta data written into the padded area. I have attempted to use the binman tool by adding a binman node to the u-boot device tree imx6dl-nitrogen6x.dts I built the board with nitrogen6dl_defconfig. Everything builds OK. The trouble occurs when I try to run the binman tool from the build directory ./tools/binman/binman -B . I get the error Binman: cannot import name QUIET_NOTFOUND. This appears to be related to the libfdt import. My understanding ends here.

I am building on Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5.2 and Python 2.7.12 (though the shebang selects 3 and I tried 2 with different errors. I also tried aliasing python to python 3 for good measure. I built u-boot with Linaro 7.5-2019.12 and the head of u-boot trunk. I also tried 5.1 Linaro and a u-boot release from 2017 for good measure with the same result. I was sure to install the dependencies (python-pyelftools, python3-pyelftools, lzma-alone, liblz4-tool) as listed in the README for the binman. I am out of ideas.

Comment: Without knowing your code it is hard to say what is wrong. Adding a link to your Github repository would help. Furthermore, please, add the sequence of commands you are using.

Comment: The repo in question is https://gitlab.denx.de/u-boot/u-boot.git Tip of master. The tool is under tools/binman.